# Get data from unknown website using Webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'm currently creating an app where people can book online from a specific website. (The website is NOT owned by me) but is there any way I can get the user input from the website?

My idea is to let a user book from the webpage and their information like name, phone and last name will be saved into my app.

So if a user enter their first and last name on the webpage, I wanna retrieve the input as a string so I can later on create a notification when it's time to attend the booked event. Is there any way to do this?

```
webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('first_3').value") { (data, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("test", data)
    }
}
```

I've added this one to the app, and I found the id "first_3" by viewing the elements.

So, how can I get the user input from a web view into my app?

Comment: exactly how you have tried already, use javascript to read the values

Comment: @Scriptable Where should I put this code?  Atm I've it below webView.load(); and I'm not getting any data when I print "data". So, how can I get the data when a button on the webpage is tapped? Like an "onClick" on a button inside the web view?

Comment: you'll probably need to write some javascript to hook into the click event of a submit button or something similar, which will then grab all of the values and send them back to you